# How to run pyspark with jar files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a jar file that need to be attached when I am running pyspark. How do I run pyspark with jar files? Below are some codes I tried, what am I doing wrong here?

script.py has python code like. I want to run this as pyspark application.

```
print "Hello world"
```

## Below runs fine but does not run on pyspark

```
spark-submit --jars somejarfile2.1.0.jar  script.py
```

## Codes tried: (runs but doesn't show the output of Hello world).

```
pyspark --jar somejarfile2.1.0.jar  script.py
```

Thank you!

Comment: Correct syntax is ` --jars JARS`. What do you mean by _does not run_?

Comment: spark-submit is running on python. I need it to use python + spark, i.e. pyspark. I have some pyspark libraries invoked into script.py. Though spark-submit is spark, I am getting errors stating that pyspark is not running with spark-submit.

Comment: `spark-submit` works just fine with Python code, and there is nothing wrong with using `--jars` there. Please post reproducible example and errors you see.

Comment: I'll take a look into this. thanks.

Comment: You could also set spark.driver.extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf (which is the conf folder of your spark install)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run spark job then you need to use

```
spark-submit --master <mode> --jars <jar_file> <code>.py
```

or else if you want to run a pyspark shell then you need to specify jar.

```
pyspark --jars JAR1, JAR2, JAR3
```